# × Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb4Be.png)I think this error is because I'm calling the setState inside the function, but I'm not sure and i don't know how to fix it.

This is one of many tries trying to make a board for a mine sweeper game but I'm having a hard time, I'm getting this error every time i try anything to make the two dimensional array that makes the board into only one array, so I have it divided into cells.

[This is the index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx0aB.png)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./board.css";

function Board(props) {
  const [cells, setCells] = useState([]);

  const createBoard = () => {
    let board = new Array(props.rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      board[i] = new Array(props.columns);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < props.columns; j++) {
        board[i][j] = {
          isMine: false,
          isOpen: false,
          isFlag: false,
          x: i,
          y: j,
        };
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.mines; i++) {
      let randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * props.rows);
      let randomColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * props.columns);
      board[randomRow][randomColumn].isMine = true;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < props.columns; j++) {
        setCells(cells.concat(board[i][j]));
      }
    }

    return board;
  };

  console.table(createBoard());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Board</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: @OlexandrPoplavskyi Too many re-renders

Comment: When I'm trying to run the code it doesn't crash. What version of React are you using and please provide a screenshot of the error.

Comment: @Puk I'm on version 16.13.1, and i put the picture in the description

Comment: The problem may be actually in your src/index.js as the rendering issue starts from there. When posting questions, the more context you can provide, the better. It'd be great if you could paste a snippet of your code in index.js (where the error is shown to be thrown from) and App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try useEffect hook to avoid re-renders. I recommend you read the documents in React's website.
The issue is you're changing the state directly in the render method, changing the state will re-render the component and you're changing it over and over again, that's the infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {

  const createBoard = () => {
    let board = new Array(props.rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      board[i] = new Array(props.columns);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < props.columns; j++) {
        board[i][j] = {
          isMine: false,
          isOpen: false,
          isFlag: false,
          x: i,
          y: j,
        };
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.mines; i++) {
      let randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * props.rows);
      let randomColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * props.columns);
      board[randomRow][randomColumn].isMine = true;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < props.columns; j++) {
        setCells(cells.concat(board[i][j]));
      }
    }

    return board;
  };

  console.table(createBoard());
}, []);
```